# Split a phrase into words and write a TXT

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to `split` a phrase into words and then, saving those words into a `TXT` like a list to do some operations later. Also I want to add more words when I write more phrases into the archive.

This is my function to do that:

```
def writetxt(phrase):
    f = open("file.txt", "a")
    words = phrase.split()
    for word in words:
        print (word)
        f.write(words.append(word))
    f.close()
```

However, it does not function and my file does not have data.

Thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: You haven't asked a question...

Comment: I want to know how to do it, because it does not function. Thanks

Comment: Change it to:
   ` for word in palabras:`

Comment: Yes, it was my error translating my code into english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def writetxt(phrase):
    f = open("file.txt", "a")
    phrase = f.read()
    palabras = phrase.split()
    for word in palabras:
        print (word)
        f.write(word)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! and how can I write the words one below the other? Because the words are written together without spaces

Comment: Append a newline ('\n')  with `word` while writing in file.